# Display tt_address records when inserted via "insert record" in TYPO3 8.7

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I'm looking for a way to display tt_address elements that were inserted with the "insert record" content element in TYPO3 8.7 LTS. I'm aware of a way with css_styled_content but i can't figure out how to do it with fluid_styled_content. Somebody on Slack pointed me to the "RECORDS" TS-Object and maybe the DatabaseQueryProcessor. Sadly, i can't find good tutorials or documentations for my usecase. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches

**Custom Content Element for tt_address**

That's the right way.

You can check how TYPO3 itself does it within the "shortcut" content element, which is "Insert Records" from the editor point of view.

The hints are totally valid. Use FLUIDTEMPLATE to define the template to render and add the DatabaseQueryProcessor as documented here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#dataprocessing

The processor can be found in the source code: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/DataProcessing/DatabaseQueryProcessor.php#L22 with an example configuration inside the PHPDoc, which already uses tt_address.

Here a complete TypoScript example for the content element:

```
tt_content.custom_content =< lib.contentElement
tt_content.custom_content {
    templateName = TtAddressRecords
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        10 {
            table = tt_address
            pidInList = 123
            as = addresses
        }
    }
}
```

**Using existing shortcut Content Element**

If you are using the native shortcut content element already, this should work out of the box, with some configurations. It will resolve the selected records.

First of all you have to allow rendering of tt_address records through this element. Therefore add the following to the TypoScript Constants:

```
styles {
    content {
        shortcut {
            tables := addToList(tt_address)
        }
    }
}
```

This will add tt_address to the existing tt_content table.

Next you need the rendering definition for tt_address records. This is done in TypoScript Setup. E.g. add the following TypoScript to the setup and adjust paths to your need:

```
tt_address < lib.contentElement
tt_address {
    templateName = TtAddress
    templateRootPaths {
        10 = EXT:cdx_site/Resources/Private/Templates/Plugins/
    }
}
```

The above example will use the Fluid Templates *cdx_site/Resources/Private/Templates/Plugins/TtAddress.html* to render each single tt_address record.

There should be no need to adjust the Shortcut.html template, as it will just display the rendered records.

Comment: Your answer looks really good to me but somehow i can't get it to work. I tried your TS and the Examples mentioned. The tt_address records are inserted with the "insert records" (shortcut) method. I checked the pidInList and the template paths (tried different things). The only thing i can display at the moment is when i insert debug info to the Shortcut.html (fluid template override). Nothing gets loaded from my custom template.  Do you think there are changes to make for the tt_content.shortcut typoscript? I guess i need someone to help me with this (paid). Contact me please if interested.

Comment: i tried it all again with a fresh install - couldn't find my error. my solution for now is a dirty one, therefore i just describe it here: i installed the ext "cyz_address" which can be used to display tt_address records with fluid templates. then i copied they way the news extensions is setup for the shortcut ctype (insert records). The plugin gets called now and it works for me, but i had to hack the cyz_address ext a little bit. i guess the normal way is much cleaner and should be easier but i couldn't get it to run and therefore i used the described workaround.